# Adding markers to an unfolding map in java

Tags: java, markers

I saw answers to questions on the `EarthquakeCityMap` assignment from `Coursera` but have a question about one of the answers. I don't have enough points to make a comment.

Why do you need to create a variable that just updates 1 `SimplePointMarker` rather than put it directly in the marker array?

The answer code is below:

```
//add this in setup method
for (PointFeature ia: earthquakes) {
    SimplePointMarker to = createMarker(ia);//using given helper method
    to.setRadius(10.0f);
    Object magObj = ia.getProperty("magnitude");
    float mag = Float.parseFloat(magObj.toString());
    if(mag >= 5.0f ){
        to.setColor(red);
    } else if(mag >= 4.0f ){
        to.setColor(yellow);
    } else {
        to.setColor(blue);
    }
    markers.add(to);//adding created simplepointmarkers to(to) arraylist
}//end of for loop

map.addMarkers(markers)//entire list of markers is  added to map
```